# SConfig - option 12). restore graphical user interface - not present

Tags: windows-server-2012

Started off with a Server Core install to which I then added the GUI with:
  Install-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Shell, Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra

So far so good, I then removed the GUI again to get back to text only mode with:
 Remove-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Shell, Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra

Now at this point I should beable to use SConfig option 12 to reinstall the GUI again but that SConfig option is missing:
 "12) Restore Graphical User Interface (GUI)"
not present, how can I get SConfig to display this option?

Has anyone else noticed that this option is missing.

Thanks,
   Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sconfig option 12 is still a little buggy it seems. I would just continue using Powershell to install/uninstall the GUI components. Sconfig is a nice little auxiliary utility but you don't need it.

These two guys both talk about the same thing, that it seems a little buggy:
http://masteringwindows.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-switch-between-windows-server-8_29.html

http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/lrayl/archive/2012/03/11/windows-server-8-beta-%E2%80%93-switching-between-core-and-gui.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From what I can establish SConfig option 12) 'Restore Graphical User Interface (GUI)' was present in Server 8 beta and preview but looks to have been removed from Server 2012 final.